# Информация из mongodb не выводится в элемент pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, pug

В схеме базы данных есть ключ Biography, его то нам и надо вывести в модальное окно документа PUG. В PUG ничего не выводится.

Вот схема:

```js
const characterSchema = new Schema({
    desc: String,
    tag: String,
    info: String,
    creator: String,
    state: Object,
    account: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        index: true,
        ref: 'Account'
    },
    site: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Auth'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    flags: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    lastUsed: {
        type: Date,
        index: true
    },
    biography: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
}, { timestamps: true });
```

Вот модель:

```js
export const Character = model<ICharacter>('Character', characterSchema);
```

Функция запроса id пользователя:

```js
export async function exportBiography(res:any, accountId: ID){
    const modalb = await Character.findById(accountId); 
    res.render('index', { modalb: JSON.stringify(modalb) });
}
```

Обращение к функции в конструкции switch (фрагмент):

```js
            case PlayerAction.ShowModal:
                app.get(this.client.accountId, (req: any, res: any) => {
                    exportBiography(res, req.parrams.id);
                  });
```

Непосредственно модальное окно в PUG, куда и нужно вывести наш ключ (попытка вывести нужные данные в .modal-content):

```js
            .modal-overlay
                .modal
                    a.close-modal
                      svg(viewbox='0 0 20 20')
                        path(fill='#000000' d='M15.898,4.045c-0.271-0.272-0.713-0.272-0.986,0l-4.71,4.711L5.493,4.045c-0.272-0.272-0.714-0.272-0.986,0s-0.272,0.714,0,0.986l4.709,4.711l-4.71,4.711c-0.272,0.271-0.272,0.713,0,0.986c0.136,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.492,0.203c0.179,0,0.357-0.067,0.493-0.203l4.711-4.711l4.71,4.711c0.137,0.136,0.314,0.203,0.494,0.203c0.178,0,0.355-0.067,0.492-0.203c0.273-0.273,0.273-0.715,0-0.986l-4.711-4.711l4.711-4.711C16.172,4.759,16.172,4.317,15.898,4.045z')
                        // close modal
                    .modal-content
                        | {{modalb.biography}}
```

Comment: Вы в pug передаёте строку, и пытаетесь взять у неё поле `biography`. Это всегда будет `undefined`.

Comment: Здесь совершенно не понятно какой контекст выполнения у PUG файла. Если вы его через Node.js собираете, тогда можно посмотреть какие данные в него пришли через консоль. В PUG файле в самом начале строки напишите следующее `- console.log("modalb-data:", typeof(modalb), modalb)`, во время сборки PUG-файла по идее должно вывести в консоль дамп о переменной `modalb`

Comment: @AlexanderYukal в консоль выводит следующее: "modalb-data: undefined undefined".

Comment: Что и требовалось доказать... При сборке PUG-файла у вас отсутствует переменная `modalb`. Почему её там не оказалось никто вам не скажет, кто ж знает что у вас там под капотом происходит?!

Comment: @AlexanderYukal  Хм, механизм не очень жизнеспособный... В таком случае существует ли возможность передать строковые данные из схемы с помощью веб-сокетов?

Comment: Я просто ума не приложу что у вас там за процесс такой эпический, чем дальше мы будем рассматривать этот вопрос тем все больше это превращается в чат и выходит за рамки `Stackoverflow`. Во вторых, надо понимать что `pug` - это html-препроцессор, приставка "пре" говорит о том что использование данной технологии необходимо перед использованием на продакшене. Если вы прям на продакшене пытаетесь его компилировать - вы явно делаете что-то не то и данный вопрос нужно задать в ином ключе.

Comment: На знаю как вы собираете `pug` но если вы пользуетесь `gulp`, у него есть плагин для передачи данных в контекст текущей сборки:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-data
Также на своем Github профиле я реализовал автоматическую загрузку данных используя статические файлы, смотрите тут: https://github.com/yukal/gulp-json-loader